# Reusing cell with textfield

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom cell with a UITextfield inside.
This cell have different behaviors for different type of models.
For example, i can have a model to present a number or other to present a date.

If is a number, it only can introduce numbers, if it´s a date when the user start to type on the textfield, a uipicker appear to select the date.

In the method cellForRow I set the textfield´s delegate to the model witch will implement each behavior for the cell.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Get Element
    SuperElement * elem = [self.arrayFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //Get Cell of the element
    SuperCell *cell = (SuperCell*)[elem returnCellForCollectionView:collectionView andIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

**DateElement**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)returnCelForCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView andIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

    SuperCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[SuperCell reuseIdentifier]
                                                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textField.text = self.value;
    cell.textField.delegate =self;

return cell; }

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    //code to show picker
}
```

**NumberElement**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)returnCelForCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView andIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

        SuperCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[SuperCell reuseIdentifier]
                                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textField.text = self.value;
        cell.textField.delegate =self;

    return cell;
}
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string
{
   //reg to accept only numbers
}
```

My problem is when the table is reloaded, for example when the user start editing the textfield a date picker appears in a number of model.
In my custom cell i try to clean when it will be reused, but no effect

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{

    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    self.textField.delegate = nil;

 }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

## Edit

If i set the inputView of the textfield to nil in the prepareForReuse´ method

```
self.textField.inputView = nil;
```

the picker don't appear. However i am adding a "Done" button in the datePicker, and that button still appear.

## Edit 2

To remove the done button, just clean the inputAcessoryView of the textField
    self.textField.inputAcessoryView = nil;

[image]

Comment: `self.textField.text = @""`?

Comment: the problem is when the user will edit the textfield. For example it appear a DatePicker instead of a numeric keyboard, probably because the cell was previous with a model of date.

Comment: Show the code where a date picker comes up for that text field instead of a keyboard.

Comment: try `self.textField.inputView = nil;`

Comment: @MichaelDautermann just updated my question

Comment: to get rid of done set self.textfield.inputAccessoryView = nil;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `texfields` property `inputView`, to set input mode. When you are setting delegate to nil, this property remains unchanged, so does the behaviour which you want to get rid off.

Documentation states:

> If the value in this property is nil, the text field displays the standard system keyboard when it becomes first responder. Assigning a custom view to this property causes that view to be presented instead.
>
> The default value of this property is nil.

Example:
**DateElement**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)returnCelForCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView andIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    SuperCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[SuperCell reuseIdentifier]
                                                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textField.text = self.value;
    cell.textField.delegate =self;
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    cell.textField.inputView = datePicker;

return cell; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- (UITextField *) textField {

     if (!_textField) {

          _textField = [[UITextField alloc] init.....];
          // Basically customize your textfield here
     }

     return _textField;
}


-(void)prepareForReuse {

    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];

    [self.textField removeFromSuperView];
    self.textField = nil;
}
```